# Radio button inserts only 1 value into SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, radio-button

I have a simple form that should insert radio button value into database:

```
<form method="post" action="insert.php">
 <input type="radio" name="yes" value="1"/>Yes<br />
 <input type="radio" name="yes" value="0"/>No
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"/><br />
</form>
```

However, in the database, there is always inserted only value 1.

Could you please help me with this? Here is insert.php

```
$var = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['yes']);

$sql="INSERT INTO table (value)
VALUES ('$var')";
```

Kindly thank you for advice.

Comment: Radio button values that have not been selected are not sent to PHP via POST.

Comment: Thank you @JayBlanchard. I want to insert value = 1 if first option is selected and value = 2 for the second option. For some reason if secon button (value 0) is selected, the script inserts value = 1.

Comment: If you want the value 2 change your second radio button's value to 2. Then select it and submit.

Comment: See this example - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/pc0k3ebt/ In order to see the results open your browser's console.

Comment: I just tried that. Still, second option inserts value = 1 (i.e. value of the first option). Do you know, where might be the problem?

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST)` show?

Comment: It says Value [yes] => 2 [submit]. However, this let me to examine the field type in database, which was binary, then I corrected it for INT type. Kindly thank you @JayBlanchard. I've been solving this for a while.

Comment: I'm glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

We Use Radio Buttons To Send One Data Only. If you want to use multiple data, use checkbox.

**Checkboxes** are mainly use when presenting the user with a number of options, of which, they can select more than one option. 
For example, Like `courses-> PHP, Java, C#, C, C++.` The user can check multiple courses.

But, **Radio buttons** are generally used when presenting the user with an "either/or" option. The user is presented with two or more options, of which, the user can only select one option. For Example, Like `Gender-> Male or Female`. The user can only select one.